# file_get_contents() is still run even in else statement that doesn't run

Tags: php, if-statement

I have something pretty weird going on where I'm sure I'm doing something really dumb, but at this point I'll take all help I can get.

Opening url: xxx/order/?type=samples&quote=643&decoration=no&quantity=10000&user=16

Note **quote** is set.

Now I've got this PHP code (it's inside a WordPress page but I don't think that matters):

```
if (isset($_GET['quote'])) {
    $order_id = $_GET['quote'];
    $product= get_field('product_link',$order_id);
    $no = 1;
} else {
    $product=$_GET['product'];
    $user = $_GET['user'];
    $unit_cost = get_field('10k_base_cost', $product)*(1+(get_field('duties', $product)/100))*(1+(get_field('markup', $product)/100));
    $product_moq = get_field('moq', $product);
    $product_moq = intval($product_moq);
    $site_url = get_site_url(); 
    $url = $site_url."/request-quote/?product=".$product."&decoration_1=0&decoration_2=0&decoration_3=0&decoration_4=0&quantity=".$product_moq."&unit_cost=".urlencode($unit_cost)."&user=".$user."&supress_redirect=1";
    $order_id =file_get_contents($url);
}
```

Now... file_get_contents calls a file that runs some code. Should only be called when quote isn't set. However, it is **always** ran. Without values (I think) set (i.e. product etc) but still, always ran.

How is beyond me but I'm sure it's obvious. Not a "professional programmer" here :-)

1. I've tried to separate it between if XX and if !XXX
2. I've tried to make it a CURL requests vs. file_get_contents

Thanks for any pointer in the right direction...

Comment: It's not run from this piece of code... if/else is NOT broken. Either you're wrong about the GET parameter, or there is other code (not shown here) which executes a file_get_contents.

Comment: Can you var_dump($_GET) and show the result?